# Solving matrix equation

Tags: matrix, julia

Say I have matrix equation on the form

```
MAM^-1 = [0.55 0.06; -0.55 0.96]
```

Where
    `A = [x_1 0; 0 x_2]`

```
 M = [1 1; 2x_1/(1 - 2x_1) 2x_2/(1 - 2x_2)]
```

So A is a 2x2 diagonal matrix and M is 2x2 matrix. I am very new to Julia so I'm only familiar with solving systems on the form Ax = b. I have managed to solve the above by hand (which was a pain!) but is there a way to solve such matrix equations in Julia?

Apologies for the poor formatting but apparently you cannot write TeX equations in stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you see the \ operator?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used \ when solving simple systems such as Ax = b but I am unsure of how to apply it to my case. Should I make a function which takes x_1,x_2 as inputs and somehow uses \ to solve the system?

Comment: Yes, unless you're looking for it to be done symbolically. The numerical way scales much better than the symbolic way though. If you do want to do it symbolically, check out [SymEngine.jl](https://github.com/symengine/SymEngine.jl#working-with-vector-and-matrix-variables). All of the same commands work on this, so just create the matrix and use \ to get the symbolic solution, but note this solution grows fast with the matrix size!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll try doing it both ways and see if I can figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You have 4 equations (your 2x2 matrix components) and 2 unknowns.

> => I the general case there is no solution to your problem.

---

**Long answer:**

To complete the answer, we can imagine something close (but different) to your problem:

Your expression `MAM^-1 = B` can be interpreted as an eigen decomposition.

`A` is your diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of `B`. `M` is the change of basis matrix containing the associated eigen vectors.

In julia:

```
B=[0.55 0.06;-0.55 0.96]
A=diagm(eigvals(B))
M=eigvecs(B)
```

> ```
> julia> B=[0.55 0.06;-0.55 0.96]
> 2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
>   0.55  0.06
>  -0.55  0.96
>
> julia> A=diagm(eigvals(B))
> 2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
>  0.66  0.0 
>  0.0   0.85
>
> julia> M=eigvecs(B)
> 2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
>  -0.478852  -0.196116
>  -0.877896  -0.980581
> ```

Now observe that

```
M*A*inv(M)
```

is your `B` matrix.

You can get a `M` matrix even closer to your proposition by scaling the eigenvectors (please note this does not modify the eigenspace nor the eigenvalues). This can be done by:

```
Mp=M*inv(diagm(M[1,:]))
```

> ```
> 2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
>  1.0      1.0
>  1.83333  5.0
> ```

You can check that you still have:

```
Mp*A*inv(Mp) # equal to your B matrix
```

> ```
> 2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
>   0.55  0.06
>  -0.55  0.96
> ```

Now, back to your initial problem, by identification we have:

From A matrix diagonal

```
x1=0.66
x2=0.85
```

From Mp second row

```
2x_1/(1 - 2x_1) = 1.83333 
2x_2/(1 - 2x_2) = 5.0
```

which is an incompatible set of equations (4 equation, 2 unknows).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I'll have to read it a couple of times before I fully understand it but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am pleased that it helped. I have clarified  the explanation (end of the answer with the "Now back to your initial problem....")

Comment: Thank you so much for the added explanation, it is exactly what I was trying to figure out. The "From A matrix diagonal" solution you obtained were the values I needed to find. I do apologise for the confusion that arose due to me saying that this was an equation that needed to be solved - This problem comes from an econometrics model I am trying to solve. Either way, thank you for taking your time and providing such a thorough answer. I truly appreciate it.